# Why isn't my php sending my contact form input to my email?

Tags: php, html, apache, web, xampp

I am trying to write some PHP which will submit my "contact form" and send the input to a given email.

On the internet, I found the following code that does this:

```html
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("vik.srk@hotmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

When I click submit, nothing is being sent to my inbox!

Comment: We need more informations like the config files you edited, and the location from your browser's address bar

Comment: PHP is not enabled on your XAMPP.

Comment: Make sure you use the server address, not the file address "

Comment: Sorry guys, it's working now. But there's still a problem, edited above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please do not use code snippet for PHP, since the code snippet cannot interpret it, rather use code sample (fifth icon : `{}` or via ctrl+k shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code to actually test if the mail was sent... I suspect you haven't configured an SMTP Email server, which means PHP has no way to send an email.

Your code now checks if mail() was successful.

```html
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        $MailSent = mail("vik.srk@hotmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        if($MailSent == true) {
             echo 'Mail Sent';
        } else {
             echo 'Mail failed';    
        }
    }   
?>
```

If it fails, then you know there's a problem with the mail function.  You can also put `error_reporting(-1)` at the top to turn on errors, in case you have any syntax errors.  Like I said before, I'm guessing you haven't configured a mail server which is why you aren't getting any emails.